# Fn key in Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

I need to use the fn key in my Selenium test. Unfortuntely, there is no way around it. Is there any work around ?

Thank you

I havent found an answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this in Selenium. However, there are some workarounds that you can use. One approach is to use the Keys.chord() method to simulate pressing multiple keys at the same time. For example, the following code will simulate pressing the "fn" key and the "1" key simultaneously:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("some-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.sendKeys(element, Keys.chord(Keys.FN, Keys.NUMPAD1)).perform();
```